# no field settings in block views?

Tags: 7, views

coming from D6, Im confused about why I can't seem to choose which fields from a content type I want to be displayed when I want to use the view as block? I searched for drupal 7 views fields settings but the results weren't about this particular issue.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. It is helpful to answerers if you elaborate your questions more.  What did you do in D6?  WHat is different? etc.. I am not sure if my answer addresses your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the content link on the 'show' line in the format section of the block definition (first column), you can switch the format to fields and then the available fields can be added.  You may want to view the video learning series at nodeone.se called "Taming the Beast' for more on how to use Views.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a bunch